# WTForms not saving correct datatype to datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Python Flask application which uses WTForms and Google Cloud Datastore. Regardless of the WTForms field type I use the value is saved as a string.

I have looked at the standard way of defining a model in python flask but thought WTForms model declaration was all that was needed.

model

```
Project_Description = TextAreaField('Project Description')
```

template

```
{{ form.Project_Description (rows='10',
  class_="govuk-textarea govuk-!-width-two-thirds",)
}}
```

datastore create/update functionality

```
def update(self, data, id=None):
    if id:
        key = client.key('ProjectDetails', int(id))
    else:
        key = client.key('ProjectDetails')

    entity = datastore.Entity(key=key, exclude_from_indexes=('Project_Description'))
    entity.update(data)
    client.put(entity)

    return Datastore_Client().from_datastore(entity)
```

I am removing ProjectDescription from indexing as when i do get it to save as text or blob I dont want a low limit on amount of bytes. When i submit the form the data is stored as a standard string rather than text or blob. I would prefer to save as a blob but unsure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Cloud Datastore libraries any unindexed text has has the 1MB-89 bytes size limit as documented in the [Entity concepts](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#text_string) documentation.  Alternatively, if you store your project description as [bytes](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/entities.html) instead of a str in python 3, then the value will be stored as a blobl